# Unity Button On Click(). public void Method() vs public void Method(arr1[], arr2[], arr3[])

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and programming.
When I try to initiate method() Button On Click (see picture),

[image]

for some reason I can not initiate public void LockPickTrigger(int[] lockPick1, int[] lockPick2, int[] lockPick3), but public void LockPickTrigger() works just fine. How can I initiate the first method?
Here is the code:
(Scroll down to "Here starts the code")

```
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private Button LockPick1;
[SerializeField] private Button LockPick2;
[SerializeField] private Button LockPick3;

[SerializeField]
private Text LockPickText1;
[SerializeField]
private Text LockPickText2;
[SerializeField]
private Text LockPickText3;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject LockBullet;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject LockBullet1;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject LockBullet2;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject LockBullet3;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject LockBullet4;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //Unimportant, scroll down
    int a = Random.Range(-2, 2);
    int c = Random.Range(-2, 2);
    int e = Random.Range(-2, 2);
    int g = Random.Range(-2, 2);
    int h = Random.Range(-2, 2);

    int[] lockPick1 = new int[] { a, c, e, g, h };
    int[] lockPick2 = new int[] { e, c, a, h, g };
    int[] lockPick3 = new int[] { h, g, e, c, a };

    LockPickText1.text = "a = " + lockPick1[0].ToString() + " c = " + lockPick1[1].ToString() + " e = " + lockPick1[2].ToString() + "\n" + " g = " + lockPick1[3].ToString() + " h = " + lockPick1[4].ToString();
    LockPickText2.text = "a = " + lockPick2[0].ToString() + " c = " + lockPick2[1].ToString() + " e = " + lockPick2[2].ToString() + "\n" + " g = " + lockPick2[3].ToString() + " h = " + lockPick2[4].ToString();
    LockPickText3.text = "a = " + lockPick3[0].ToString() + " c = " + lockPick3[1].ToString() + " e = " + lockPick3[2].ToString() + "\n" + " g = " + lockPick3[3].ToString() + " h = " + lockPick3[4].ToString();

    //Here starts the code
    LockPickTrigger(lockPick1, lockPick2, lockPick3);
}

public void LockPickTrigger()
{

}

public void LockPickTrigger(int[] lockPick1, int[] lockPick2, int[] lockPick3)
{
    Vector3 Bullet = new Vector3(lockPick1[0], lockPick1[0], 0);
    LockBullet.transform.position = LockBullet.transform.position + Bullet;
}
```

Comment: whats the name of the class? could you post the full code?

Comment: Just added everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inspector only lets you assign callback functions that take zero or one arguments, and there are only a few allowed types for the argument (bool, int, float and GameObject). However, instead of adding this function from inspector, you can add the function as a button onClick listener in code like this:

```
void Start()
{
    LockPick1.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        int[] lockPick1 = GetLockPick1Values();
        int[] lockPick2 = GetLockPick2Values();
        int[] lockPick3 = GetLockPick3Values();
        LockPickTrigger(lockPick1, lockPick2, lockPick3);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified it a little and it worked! LockPick1.onClick.AddListener(() => {
            LockPickTrigger1(lockPick1, lockPick2, lockPick3);
        });

Comment: @Maxkiel you know i feel like this defeats the purpose of unityEvents a bit, you know being able to assign events from the inspectore. now its all code again (i prefer it but others might not) i wonder why unity only allows 0..1 arguments with a specific type...

Answer (score 1):

I have not much experience regarding unity UI (i use Noesis UI) but from what i could gather the onclick event can only have one argument or none at all. so `myFunc()` and `myFunc(string a)` works but not `myFunc(string a, string b)`

So you should perhaps refactor your code so you don't need those arguments, or put all arguments in a single class and use that instead (i believe that could also work, but i've only read from sources online)

Here's a quick list with more solutions:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/923959/ui-system-multiple-ints-as-function-arguments.html?childToView=925288#answer-925288

Although it would help to know what you're actually trying to achieve.